# sql How to replace thousands of unique values with new unique values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table:

```
key, value
1, ...
2, ...
3, ...
```

I now need to replace many thousand keys

```
oldkey, newkey
1, 4
3, 7
```

result

```
key, value
4, ...
2, ...
7, ...
```

Is there a practical way to do this without having thousands of update queries?
Would case when be performant?

Comment: Will any old values show up as new values too?

Comment: No the old and new values will all be unique (they are actually hashes)

Answer (score 2):

Update them with an INNER JOIN like:

```
     UPDATE upd
        SET upd.key = mapping_table.newkey
       FROM table_to_update upd
 INNER JOIN mapping_table
         ON upd.key = mapping_table.oldkey
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably needing inner join

```
SELECT b.newkey,a.value
FROM OLDKEYS a INNER JOIN NEWKEYS b
ON a.key = b.oldkey;
```

If there is a need, you can use this logic for updates as well